# CSS display temporarily changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

High-level, I'm trying to make it so when you click a link, a div fades out and another fades in. However, when you click the link that it was originally set to, it briefly (1 second or less) moves the div to the bottom left of the screen and then back into place. This only happens on clicking the link that will return it to its default position.

Here's some relevant code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.nav-link').click(function() {
    var linkClicked = $(this).attr("id");
    $('.content').fadeOut('fast')


    switch(linkClicked) {

        case 'home': 
            console.log("linkClicked = "+linkClicked);
            $('#home-content').fadeIn('slow', function() {
                $(this).css("display", "inline");
                $(this).css("opacity", 100);
                });
            break;

        case 'where':
            console.log("linkClicked = "+linkClicked);
            $('#where-content').fadeIn('slow', function() {
                $(this).css("display", "inline");
                $(this).css("opacity", 100);
            });
            break;
```

So when I click "where" it works fine, but when I click "home" it has the weird behavior. I believe it is momentarily ignoring the "inline" display property for some reason?

Comment: If "where" works but "home" doesn't then the problem must be with the css or html because the code is identical. Please post the relevant css and html.

Comment: My guess is that the issue has to do with how you page elements are formatted.  Please post code... and create a jsfiddle.

Comment: can you post your html as well?

Answer (score 1):

I can see your problem now, basically if you want to fade one in and fade one out at the exact same time and you have their css as display:inline you will get this moving effect because one is trying to fade out while the other is coming back in so they are there are the same time for a fraction of a second.

The way to fix this is to either change:
a) change your css so the two boxes are on top of each other and absolutely positioned with z-indexes

or b) change it so the first one just hides itself rather than fades out like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav-link').click(function() {
    var linkClicked = $(this).attr("id");
    $('.content').hide();
    switch(linkClicked) {
        case 'home': 
            $('#home-content').fadeIn('slow');
            break;
        case 'where':
            $('#where-content').fadeIn('slow');
            break;
    }   
  });
});
```

jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/MuA3L/

Comment: I actually found an alternate solution which was to setTimeout after the fadeOut effect and before the switch case. This would have worked too though!